# How to insert an array in a loop to the database

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, database-connection, hana

I want to insert a set of arrays into a database(HANA) in a loop.My code is below:

```
public class jdemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Connection connection = null;
      try {                  
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:sap://myhdb:30715/?autocommit=false",myname,mysecret);                  
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         System.err.println("Connection Failed. User/Passwd Error?");
         return;
      }
      if (connection != null) {
         try {
            int [] array=new int []{1,2,3};
            Array array1= connection.createArrayof("Integer",array)
            System.out.println("Connection to HANA successful!");
            String sql="INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(1,ARRAY(?))"
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.createStatement(sql);
            stmt.setArray(int,array1);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

       } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.err.println("Query failed!");
       }
     }
   }
}
```

But this does not work.
I tried with

```
Object [] array=new Object []{1,2,3};
```

This returned method create array of Connection is not supported.

My Table Schema looks like

```
ID   MARK
__   ____
10  {1,2,3}
11  {3,2,3}
12  {9,2,3}
13  {10,2,3}
14  {12,24,3}
18  {1,27,3}
```

I also want my data type as an integer array.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what does your TABLE1 schema look like ?

Comment: is there any output to console? for eg, any exceptions or connection successful messages?

Comment: can't you use a one to many relation for that?

Comment: What do you mean with "this does not work"? Do you get an exception, or does something unexpected happen? Be specific. You might want to replace that `System.err.println("Query failed!");` with either an `e.printStackTrace()` or log the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic of "ARRAY inserts into HANA" has been discussed a couple of times here on SO already.
HANA only supports to store arrays via the ARRAY() function. This function does not take a list as the parameter, but only separate elements.

So, instead of

```
 String sql="INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(1,ARRAY(?))"
```

you would have to write

```
String sql="INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(1, ARRAY( 1, 2, 3))"
```

For the JDBC driver: HANA JDBC doesn't automatically handle JAVA arrays to HANA arrays - that's something the developer will have to do manually.
(yes, it's not nice, I know).

In short: currently (HANA 1.0 SP12) arrays can basically be used internally (within a stored procedure), but they are not first-class-citizen data types. (<- that's my opinion!)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:
Instead of storing an array in your column, you can save a string separated by colons. When you query the data from your database, you can use [split(",")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), and you automatically have your array that you need (after [Integer.parseInt(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)))

Comment: But I want to store the data in the array format because the data is not only used by program.There are several other programs(not Java) also using the data I insert.So I cannot change the data type.

Comment: @RKR you should write this to your qustion that you are forced to that schema

Answer (score 1):

You are using createStatement instead of prepareStatement.
createStatement does nut support parameters!

Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

And https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

for details
Hope this helps

Would be nice if you provide DDL, error messages etc.
 next time, then its easier to analyze.